# How to map two lists of objects by id efficiently

Tags: java

I have a `List` of objects (`List 1`) that I'm looping through. Each object has an `id` string associated with it. I have another list (`List 2`) containing a different type of object. I want to map the objects in `List 2` to my `List 1` objects. `List 1` has a `getId()` function and `List 2` has a `getList1Id()` function, that gives the `id` of the object its supposed to map to in `List 1`. How do I do this in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: Use java.util.Map instead of List.

Comment: Build a `Map<String, DifferentType>` from `List 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate over both lists and build a map using the id as key and the object as value.  E.g. for the first list:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
for (Object o : list1) {
    map1.put(o.getId(), o);
}
```

Do the same for the second list:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
for (Object o : list2) {
    map2.put(o.getId(), o);
}
```

Now you can relate an object in one list to an object in the other by calling get with a given id.